# How to detect if a Unicode character has been defined?

Tags: pdftex, unicode, expl3, input-encodings

Using `inputenc` in pdfLaTeX, one can define macros for Unicode characters like this:

```
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{03BC}{\textmu}
```

Is there a way to detect if μ has been defined? (and if so what it is defined as)?

#### Things I have tried

```
\token_if_macro:NTF { μ } {
    \iow_term:n {yes}
} {
    \iow_term:n {no}
}
```

However this always returns 'yes', as it seems that an undefined Unicode character is actually defined as a macro to give the `Unicode char ⟨charcode⟩ not set up for use with LaTeX` error message.

(Yes, I know about XeTeX and LuaTeX.)

Comment: Welcome. Do you want to know if legacy fonts or ttf/otf fonts are being used for a symbol?

Comment: I added a user interface.

Comment: Well the `\u8:` thing feels kind of like "internal API" (not sure where it's documented) but then it's part of the LaTeX kernel so it's expected to be very, very stable.

Comment: @user202729 Indeed, the `\u8:<bytes>` convention is not an “official” API, but has been the same for a couple of decades.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You want to see whether the control sequence `\u8:μ` exists when the bytes forming `μ` in UTF8 are converted to “other” characters, which is obtained by using `\detokenize` or, in `expl3` form, `\tl_to_str:n`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_if_exist:cTF { u8:\tl_to_str:n { μ } }
 { \iow_term:n {yes} }
 { \iow_term:n {no} }

\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{03BC}{\textmu}

\cs_if_exist:cTF { u8:\tl_to_str:n { μ } }
 { \iow_term:n {yes} }
 { \iow_term:n {no} }
```

The console will show

```
no
yes
```

With a user interface:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\checkunicodeTF}{mmm}
 {
  \wbob_checkunicode:nnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\checkunicodeT}{mm}
 {
  \wbob_checkunicode:nnn { #1 } { #2 } { }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\checkunicodeF}{mm}
 {
  \wbob_checkunicode:nnn { #1 } { } { #2 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \wbob_checkunicode:nnn
 {
  \cs_if_exist:cTF { u8:\tl_to_str:n { #1 } } { #2 } { #3 }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\checkunicodeTF{à}{\typeout{à is defined}}{\typeout{à is undefined}}
\checkunicodeTF{μ}{\typeout{μ is defined}}{\typeout{μ is undefined}}
\checkunicodeF{μ}{\newunicodechar{μ}{\textmu}}

\begin{document}

μ

\end{document}
```

This will print `\textmu` and show, on the console,

```
à is defined
μ is undefined
```