# \leq, \le, \leqslant and LuaLaTeX

Tags: luatex

I have a problem replacing `\leq` by `\leqslant` with LuaLaTeX (I didn't have this problem with PdfLaTeX).

Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,french]{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[warnings-off={mathtools-colon,mathtools-overbracket},math-style=french]{unicode-math}
\usepackage[default]{fontsetup}
\usepackage[scale={0.75,0.8},footskip=1.5cm,heightrounded]{geometry}


\RenewDocumentCommand{\leq}{}{\leqslant}%modification du <=


\begin{document}
    \[x\leq 3\]
\end{document}
```

And here is what I get:

[image]

The <= symbol didn't change.

But, if I type:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,french]{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[warnings-off={mathtools-colon,mathtools-overbracket},math-style=french]{unicode-math}
\usepackage[default]{fontsetup}
\usepackage[scale={0.75,0.8},footskip=1.5cm,heightrounded]{geometry}


\RenewDocumentCommand{\le}{}{\leqslant}%modification du <=


\begin{document}
    \[x\le 3\]
\end{document}
```

Here is what I get:

[image]

I don't get it because I thought `\le` and `\leq` were exactly the same. And in all my documents (there are many), I used `\leq`.

Comment: the unicode-math package does lots of its setup at begin document and then overwrites your definition again. Use `\AtBeginDocument{\RenewDocumentCommand{\leq}{}{\leqslant}}`

Comment: https://github.com/wspr/unicode-math/issues/465

Comment: Thank you both of you. I guess I will encounter other "errors" with LuaLaTeX and uni-code (I've just migrated from PdfLaTeX to LuaLaTeX)

Comment: You can also migrate from pdfLaTeX or LuaLaTeX to OpTeX. Then you have no problem with this issue, there is no "AtBeginDocument". The following works: `\fontfam[lm] \let\le=\leqslant $x\le3$ \bye`.

Answer (score 3):

You probably want the slanted variant for all inequalities, it might be tedious to redefine them one by one. Many Unicode Maths fonts have options to do that all at once (these options are called "Stylistic Sets"). Unfortunately the default fonts `NewComputerModern` you use do not have this feature. You could either suggest to the maintainer to add it or switch to other fonts.

An example with the `Erewhon` fonts:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,french]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[warnings-off={mathtools-colon,mathtools-overbracket},
            math-style=french]{unicode-math}
\usepackage[StylisticSet=4]{fourier-otf}
%\usepackage[Style=leqslant]{fourier-otf}% Same output
\usepackage[scale={0.75,0.8},footskip=1.5cm,heightrounded]{geometry}
\begin{document}
  \[x\leq 3, y\leqq 4, z\ngeq 5, t\eqless 6\]
\begin{document}
```

will print

[image]

Comment: Thank you Daniel. In fact, Newcomputermodern is just an example. I think I will use TeX Gyre Thermes. I don’t know if this font has these features. Is there any documentation about these stylistic sets? Je crois que je devrais écrire en français car c’est votre document « De pdfLaTeX à LuaLaTeX » qui m’a convaincu de passer à LuaLaTeX

Comment: The TeX Gyre fonts do not seem to have these features either… sigh.

Comment: Ok,merci Daniel

Comment: Finalement je pense utiliser fourier-otf, car avec TeX Gyre Termes, je trouve le symbole d'intégration trop petit. Il a rapetissé aussi avec Erewhon (par rapport à New Computer Modern) mais moins

Comment: @DanielFlipo Tex Gyre Termes has both symbols ≤ U+2264 LESS-THAN OR EQUAL TO and  ⩽ U+2A7D LESS-THAN OR SLANTED EQUAL TO.

Comment: @Cicada Agreed, but no `Stylistic Set` to print `\leq` and co as slanted.

Comment: @DanielFlipo A custom font feature can be coded up in lua code.

Answer (score 2):

Unicode has different codepoints for ≤ and ⩽

> ≤ U+2264 LESS-THAN OR EQUAL TO
> ⩽ U+2A7D LESS-THAN OR SLANTED EQUAL TO

and similarly for other related symbols.

If you do `\ShowCommand{\le}` after `\begin{document}`, you'll see

```
> \le=\protected macro:
->\leq .
```

With `\ShowCommand{\leq}` you get

```
> \leq=the character ≤.
```

and with `\ShowCommand{\leqslant}` you get

```
> \leq=the character ⩽.
```

Here's what you should do

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,french]{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[
  warnings-off={mathtools-colon,mathtools-overbracket},
  math-style=french
]{unicode-math}
\usepackage[default]{fontsetup}
\usepackage[scale={0.75,0.8},footskip=1.5cm,heightrounded]{geometry}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \RenewCommandCopy{\leq}{\leqslant}%
  \RenewCommandCopy{\le}{\leq}%
}


\begin{document}

\[x\leq 3 \qquad x \le 3\]

\end{document}
```

You also need to do similarly for `\geq` and `\ge` and the other inequality symbols you need to get slanted.

From `unicode-math-table`, but not all symbols with slanted dash have an unslated counterpart.

```
\UnicodeMathSymbol{"02A7D}{\leqslant                 }{\mathrel}{less-than or slanted equal to}%
\UnicodeMathSymbol{"02A7E}{\geqslant                 }{\mathrel}{greater-than or slanted equal to}%
\UnicodeMathSymbol{"02A7F}{\lesdot                   }{\mathrel}{less-than or slanted equal to with dot inside}%
\UnicodeMathSymbol{"02A80}{\gesdot                   }{\mathrel}{greater-than or slanted equal to with dot inside}%
\UnicodeMathSymbol{"02A81}{\lesdoto                  }{\mathrel}{less-than or slanted equal to with dot above}%
\UnicodeMathSymbol{"02A82}{\gesdoto                  }{\mathrel}{greater-than or slanted equal to with dot above}%
\UnicodeMathSymbol{"02A83}{\lesdotor                 }{\mathrel}{less-than or slanted equal to with dot above right}%
\UnicodeMathSymbol{"02A84}{\gesdotol                 }{\mathrel}{greater-than or slanted equal to with dot above left}%
\UnicodeMathSymbol{"02A93}{\lesges                   }{\mathrel}{less-than above slanted equal abov
e greater-than above slanted equal}%
\UnicodeMathSymbol{"02A94}{\gesles                   }{\mathrel}{greater-than above slanted equal a
bove less-than above slanted equal}%
\UnicodeMathSymbol{"02A95}{\eqslantless              }{\mathrel}{slanted equal to or less-than}%
\UnicodeMathSymbol{"02A96}{\eqslantgtr               }{\mathrel}{slanted equal to or greater-than}%
\UnicodeMathSymbol{"02A97}{\elsdot                   }{\mathrel}{slanted equal to or less-than with
 dot inside}%
\UnicodeMathSymbol{"02A98}{\egsdot                   }{\mathrel}{slanted equal to or greater-than w
ith dot inside}%
\UnicodeMathSymbol{"02A9B}{\eqqslantless             }{\mathrel}{double-line slanted equal to or le
ss-than}%
\UnicodeMathSymbol{"02A9C}{\eqqslantgtr              }{\mathrel}{double-line slanted equal to or gr
eater-than}%
\UnicodeMathSymbol{"02AA8}{\lescc                    }{\mathrel}{less-than closed by curve above slanted equal}%
\UnicodeMathSymbol{"02AA9}{\gescc                    }{\mathrel}{greater-than closed by curve above slanted equal}%
\UnicodeMathSymbol{"02AF9}{\leqqslant                }{\mathrel}{double-line slanted less-than or equal to}%
\UnicodeMathSymbol{"02AFA}{\geqqslant                }{\mathrel}{double-line slanted greater-than or equal to}%
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this very complete answer

Answer (score 2):

Lua code can do work at font-level: define your own custom font feature, including glyph substitution.

[image: leqsl]

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\directlua{
fonts.handlers.otf.addfeature {
name = "leqs",
type = "substitution",
data = {
["≤"] = "uni2A7D",
}
}
}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{texgyretermes-math.otf}[RawFeature=+leqs]

\begin{document}
 
  \[ x \leq 3 \]
\end{document}
```

---

*Edit*

Towards a more complete lookup table in Lua, defining a custom alternate style font feature.

Note that font TeX Gyre Termes - Math is missing some glyphs.

[image: font feature]

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{unicode-math}


\directlua{
fonts.handlers.otf.addfeature{
    name = "saltineq",
    type = "alternate",
    data =
    {
      ["≤"] = "⩽", %-- \leqslant
                ["≥"] = "⩾", %-- \geqslant
            ["⋜"] = "⪕", %-- \eqslantless
            ["⋝"] = "⪖", %-- \eqslantgtr
                ["⪙"] = "⪛", %-- \eqqslantless
                ["⪚"] = "⪜", %-- \eqqslantgtr
                ["≦"] = "⫹", %-- \leqqslant
            ["≧"] = "⫺", %-- \geqqslant
    },
  }
}  

    \setmainfont[
        RawFeature={+saltineq},
    ]{XITS-Regular.otf}

    \setmathfont{texgyretermes-math.otf}[
%        RawFeature={+saltineq},
    ]
    

\ExplSyntaxOn

% Adapted from:
%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/654839/how-to-detect-if-a-unicode-character-has-been-defined
\NewDocumentCommand{\cg} { m }
 {
  \wb_checkunicode:nnn { #1 } { #1 } { 
                    {\color{red}
                        \textrm{
                        #1
                        }
                    }}
 }
 
\cs_new_protected:Nn \wb_checkunicode:nnn
 {
  \cs_if_exist:cTF { u8:\tl_to_str:n { #1 } } { #2 } { #3 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
 
 
   
\begin{document}


\addfontfeature{RawFeature={-saltineq}}


\begin{longtblr}[caption={Without feature},
remark{Note}={Text = XITS; Math = TeX Gyre Termes - Math.},
]{
colspec={Q[r]Q[c]Q[c]Q[c]Q[c]Q[l]},
cell{2-Z}{1,6}={font=\ttfamily,cmd={\textbackslash}},
column{3,4}={mode=imath},
column{3}={fg=blue},
row{odd}={bg={blue!12}},
}
&T&M&M&T&\\
 leq
& \leq
& \leq
& \leqslant
& \leqslant
&  leqslant
\\
 geq
& \geq
& \geq
& \geqslant
& \geqslant
&  geqslant
\\
 eqless
& \eqless
& \eqless
& \eqslantless
& \eqslantless
&  eqslantless
\\
 eqgtr
& \eqgtr
& \eqgtr
& \eqslantgtr
& \eqslantgtr
&  eqslantgtr
\\
 leqq
& \leqq
& \leqq
& \leqqslant
& \leqqslant
&  leqqslant
\\
 geqq
& \geqq
& \geqq
& \geqqslant
& \geqqslant
&  geqqslant
\\
 eqqless
& \eqqless
& \eqqless
& \eqqslantless
& \eqqslantless
&  eqqslantless
\\
 eqqgtr
& \eqqgtr
& \eqqgtr
& \eqqslantgtr
& \eqqslantgtr
&  eqqslantgtr
\\
\end{longtblr}





\addfontfeature{RawFeature={+saltineq}}

    \setmathfont{texgyretermes-math.otf}[
        RawFeature={+saltineq},
    ]


\begin{longtblr}[caption={With feature},
note{a}={Red is \texttt{\textbackslash textrm} in math mode.},
remark{Note}={Text = XITS; Math = TeX Gyre Termes - Math.},
]{colspec={Q[r]Q[c]Q[c]Q[c]Q[c]Q[l]},
cell{2-Z}{1,6}={font=\ttfamily,cmd={\textbackslash}},
column{3,4}={mode=imath},
column{3}={fg=blue},
row{odd}={bg={blue!12}},
%cell{6-9}{3-4}={bg={red!5}},
}
&T&M&M&T&\\
 leq
& \leq
& \leq
& \leqslant
& \leqslant
&  leqslant
\\
 geq
& \geq
& \geq
& \geqslant
& \geqslant
&  geqslant
\\
 eqless
& \eqless
& \eqless
& \eqslantless
& \eqslantless
&  eqslantless
\\
 eqgtr
& \eqgtr
& \eqgtr
& \eqslantgtr
& \eqslantgtr
&  eqslantgtr
\\
 leqq
& \leqq
& \cg{\leqq}
& \cg{\leqqslant}
& \leqqslant
&  leqqslant
\\
 geqq
& \geqq
& \cg{\geqq}
& \cg{\geqqslant}
& \geqqslant
&  geqqslant
\\
 eqqless
& \eqqless
& \cg{\eqqless}
& \cg{\eqqslantless}
& \eqqslantless
&  eqqslantless
\\
 eqqgtr
& \eqqgtr
& \cg{\eqqgtr}
& \cg{\eqqslantgtr}
& \eqqslantgtr
&  eqqslantgtr
\\
\end{longtblr}


\end{document}
```

---

*Edit*

**A More Practical Example**

The font feature in math mode has to be visible to `unicode-math`, so that it is picked up on the symbol refresh.

[image: math mode]

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{unicode-math}


\directlua{
fonts.handlers.otf.addfeature{
    name = "saltineq",
    type = "alternate",
    data =
    {
      ["≤"] = "⩽", %-- \leqslant
                ["≥"] = "⩾", %-- \geqslant
            ["⋜"] = "⪕", %-- \eqslantless
            ["⋝"] = "⪖", %-- \eqslantgtr
                ["⪙"] = "⪛", %-- \eqqslantless
                ["⪚"] = "⪜", %-- \eqqslantgtr
                ["≦"] = "⫹", %-- \leqqslant
            ["≧"] = "⫺", %-- \geqqslant
    },
  }
}  

\newcommand\fontmimname{Asana Math}


    \setmathfont{texgyretermes-math.otf}[
%        RawFeature={+saltineq},
    ]
    
    \setmathfont[
                Colour=red,
                range={\eqqslantgtr,
                \eqqgtr,
                \leqqslant,
                \geqqslant,
                \eqqslantless,
                \eqqless,
                }
    ]{\fontmimname}




\begin{document}


\addfontfeature{RawFeature={-saltineq}}


\begin{longtblr}[caption={Without feature},
note{a}={Red is imported from \fontmimname{}, without the feature activated.},
remark{Note}={Text = Default; Math = TeX Gyre Termes - Math.},
]{
colspec={Q[r]Q[c]Q[c]Q[c]Q[c]Q[l]},
cell{2-Z}{1,6}={font=\ttfamily,cmd={\textbackslash}},
column{3,4}={mode=imath},
column{3}={fg=blue},
row{odd}={bg={blue!12}},
}
&T&M&M&T&\\
 leq
& \leq
& \leq
& \leqslant
& \leqslant
&  leqslant
\\
 geq
& \geq
& \geq
& \geqslant
& \geqslant
&  geqslant
\\
 eqless
& \eqless
& \eqless
& \eqslantless
& \eqslantless
&  eqslantless
\\
 eqgtr
& \eqgtr
& \eqgtr
& \eqslantgtr
& \eqslantgtr
&  eqslantgtr
\\
 leqq
& \leqq
& \leqq
& \leqqslant
& \leqqslant
&  leqqslant
\\
 geqq
& \geqq
& \geqq
& \geqqslant
& \geqqslant
&  geqqslant
\\
 eqqless
& \eqqless
& \eqqless
& \eqqslantless
& \eqqslantless
&  eqqslantless
\\
 eqqgtr
& \eqqgtr
& \eqqgtr
& \eqqslantgtr
& \eqqslantgtr
&  eqqslantgtr
\\
\end{longtblr}





\addfontfeature{RawFeature={+saltineq}}


    \setmathfont{texgyretermes-math.otf}[
        RawFeature={+saltineq},
    ]


    \setmathfont[
                RawFeature={+saltineq},
                Colour=brown,
                range={\eqqslantgtr,
                \eqqgtr,
                \leqqslant,
                \geqqslant,
                \eqqslantless,
                \eqqless,
                \leqq,
                \geqq,
                }
    ]{\fontmimname}
    
\begin{longtblr}[caption={With feature},
note{a}={Brown is imported from \fontmimname{}, with the feature activated.},
remark{Note}={Text = Default; Math = TeX Gyre Termes - Math.},
]{colspec={Q[r]Q[c]Q[c]Q[c]Q[c]Q[l]},
cell{2-Z}{1,6}={font=\ttfamily,cmd={\textbackslash}},
column{3,4}={mode=imath},
column{3}={fg=blue},
row{odd}={bg={blue!12}},
%cell{6-9}{3-4}={bg={red!5}},
}
&T&M&M&T&\\
 leq
& \leq
& \leq
& \leqslant
& \leqslant
&  leqslant
\\
 geq
& \geq
& \geq
& \geqslant
& \geqslant
&  geqslant
\\
 eqless
& \eqless
& \eqless
& \eqslantless
& \eqslantless
&  eqslantless
\\
 eqgtr
& \eqgtr
& \eqgtr
& \eqslantgtr
& \eqslantgtr
&  eqslantgtr
\\
 leqq
& \leqq
& \leqq
& \leqqslant
& \leqqslant
&  leqqslant
\\
 geqq
& \geqq
& \geqq
& \geqqslant
& \geqqslant
&  geqqslant
\\
 eqqless
& \eqqless
& \eqqless
& \eqqslantless
& \eqqslantless
&  eqqslantless
\\
 eqqgtr
& \eqqgtr
& \eqqgtr
& \eqqslantgtr
& \eqqslantgtr
&  eqqslantgtr
\\
\end{longtblr}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you , Cicada

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer, and less elegant than AtBeginDocument, but you could re-redefine inside the document. This can be restricted to a group, if desired.

[image: redefined]

MWE

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,french]{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[warnings-off={mathtools-colon,mathtools-overbracket},math-style=french]{unicode-math}
\usepackage[default]{fontsetup}
\usepackage[scale={0.75,0.8},footskip=1.5cm,heightrounded]{geometry}

\NewDocumentCommand{\oldleqslant}{}{\leqslant}%modification du <=

%%\RenewDocumentCommand{\leq}{}{\leqslant}%modification du <=


\begin{document}

    \[x\leq 3\]

\RenewDocumentCommand{\leq}{}{\oldleqslant}%modification du <=

    \[x\leq 3\]


\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion